# Сделать показ div при смене select'a

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы при выборе оптион показывался определенный блок.

Вот код. Он показывает только первые два блока, а при выборе третьего показывает все три:

```
<select id="Spisok" name="1" class="input-xlarge"><br />
<option value="0" selected="selected">Блок 1</option>
<option value="1">Блок 2</option>
<option value="2">Блок 3</option>
</select>
<br />

<div id="blokone" class="control-group" style="display:block">
block1
</div>

<div id="bloktwo" class="control-group" style="display:none">
block2
</div>

<div id="blokthree" class="control-group" style="display:none">
block3
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("Spisok")
.onchange = function () {
var b = {
0: "blokone",
1: "bloktwo",
2: "blokthree",
}, c = this.value,
a;
for (a in b) document.getElementById(b[a])
.style.display = 2 == c || c == a ? "block" : "none"
};
</script>
```

Comment: @expert, попросите, пожалуйста, редакторов не перемечать вопросы по темам, в которых они не разбираются. Метки, вроде div, span и т.п. никак не помогают в структуризации контента, это просто информационный мусор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не зная js, решил проблему, исправив строчку

```
.style.display = 3 == c || c == a ? "block" : "none"
```

Comment: Вы решили проблему тем, что сделали невозможное условие 3 == с, которое в принципе было и не нужно, напишите так и всё тоже будет работать для любого количества элементов: .style.display = c == a ? "block" : "none"